# Is it possible to put routing informations related to sub-modules to that sub-module structure in yii?

Tags: php, yii

I have an application that consists of multiple modules. Now i want to put the routing information related to specific modules to that specific module structure instead of the main.php in config under urlmanager. Because the main.php is getting larger in size if i have many nested modules. Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to split the `main.php`, it is possile such that

```
# main.php
$module1 = require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/module1.php';
$module2 = require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/module2.php';

return array( 
  ...
  'components' => array(
     'urlManager' => array_merge( array(
        'rules' => array(
            ....
        ) , $module1 , $module2 );
```

Comment: hi, this is not working for me.                                 $buyer = require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/buyer.php';         
array(
 '/'=>'buyer/home',
 '/error' => 'buyer/home/error',
 '<page_slug:[\w-]+>' => 'buyer/cms/showcontent',
'rules' => array(...),$buyer,